# Questions about custom switch button in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make a switch button like the picture.

[image]

Is there a library or method in ios that allows this switch button?

Comment: Are you wanting the switches to change color when they are selected? If that is the case, I would use a custom UIButton subclass that changes its background color/text color when selected.

Comment: If I press the button, the background will not be kept in the color specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not switch button, the control you want is the tag view.

You can use this one: https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView